# Area of a square with an arc passing through it

Tags: integration, area

Assuming the the blacks and blue arcs are quarter circles, how would I go about finding the region A+B? Region A was pretty easy to find, as it's just the area of a circle with radius $r$ divided by $4$.

Once the arc goes past $x^2 + y^2 = 100$, it gets more complicated. Letting the blue circle have the equation $x^2+y^2 = r^2$, I tried solving $\frac{\pi\cdot r^2 }{4}-2\int_{0}^{r}\int_{0}^{\sqrt{r^2-y^2}} 1 \,dxdy$ but I get an error.

How would I go about finding the area of this region? And follow-up, is there any way to get the area of this region without integrating?

[image]

Comment: Huh??  What does the largest arc have to do with the problem?  Why is it there?  For that matter, what does the smallest arc have to do with the problem?  Why is it there?

Comment: Connect the point $0$ to the two points where the arc intersects the sides of the square. You will have divided the area $A+B$ into two triangles and a circular sector. Use elementary geometry and trigonometry to calculate the areas of those, then add them up!

Comment: I was trying to show that the radius of the circle has to be greater than the side length of the square, so the black arcs are just the boundary of $r$. If the radius of the circle was less than the square's side length, the area would simply be the area of the quarter circle. Obviously I didn't do a good job at making the picture

Comment: @StinkingBishop thank you! I'll go try that right now